# MYSQL get the count of groups

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a simple MySQL that returns grouped data based on WHERE and HAVING clauses.

```
SELECT Platform, `Test Procedure`, `Order Number` 
FROM Stage 
WHERE (`StartTime` BETWEEN "2018-4-23" AND DATE_ADD("2018-4-24",INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
GROUP BY `Order Number` 
HAVING (Stage.Platform =  "Kingston") AND (Stage.`Test Procedure` = "Calibration and test")
```

I need to get the groups count, and not the count of records in each group.

Is it possible within the SQL statement or would I be better trying to access this through the ASPX.CS side ?

Answer (score 0):

Join with another query that gets the count you want.

```
SELECT Platform, `Test Procedure`, `Order Number`, `Order Count`
FROM Stage 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Order Number`) AS `Order Count`
    FROM Stage
    WHERE `StartTime` BETWEEN "2018-4-23" AND DATE_ADD("2018-4-24",INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND Stage.Platform =  "Kingston" AND Stage.`Test Procedure` = "Calibration and test"
) AS x
WHERE (`StartTime` BETWEEN "2018-4-23" AND DATE_ADD("2018-4-24",INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
AND (Stage.Platform =  "Kingston") AND (Stage.`Test Procedure` = "Calibration and test")
GROUP BY `Order Number`
```

There also doesn't seem to be any reason to put the `Platform` and `Test Procedure` tests in `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`. `HAVING` should be used for columns that are calculated in the `SELECT` list, not values that come from the table rows.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. There is slightly more code around this and I tried to clear it up to concentrate on the solution required. But in this context, yes the HAVING are not required.